# Keyboard shortcut to get focus webpage after selecting address bar

Tags: windows, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

The keyboard shortcut to select address bar (in chrome) is `Ctrl + L`, `ALT D`, or `F6`. But what is the keyboard shortcut to un-select the url and get back to the webpage? If I hit `tab`, the focus cycles within suggested urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use <kbd>F6</kbd> to select and unselect the address bar in Chrome.

Comment: this works if user doesn't have a bookmarks bar. If there is a bookmarks bar, then pressing F6 again moves focus from bookmarks back to web page.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome version 96: F6 cycles through various UI elements like tabs, address bar, bookmark bar and webpage. SHIFT+F6 is the same cycle in reverse.

To put focus back to the webpage without this cycling, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>F6</kbd> will focus onto the omnibox, and additional <kbd>F6</kbd> inputs will cycle through various control sets, eventually coming back around to the webpage (it will return focus to whatever control you left off from).

Also note that you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to cycle in reverse, and so, i.e., you can focus to omnibox <kbd>F6</kbd> and then return focus to webpage <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>.

The above is confirmed working as of Google Chrome is up to date Version 83.0.4103.61 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)