# On brave browser running macOS, what is the shortcut to focus on web page (the opposite of `control-l`)?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, brave

I am using a Macbook M1 with macOS Monterey 12.5. Also, I must
highlight that I am using a software called
[Karabiner-elements](https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements)
to tweak some keybindings. You can see [my
config](https://github.com/pdelfino/my-karabiner-elements-config)
here.

On Brave browser (and also in other browsers, such as Chrome) I can
move focus to the address bar using <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> (or <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>) as a shortcut.

I would like to know **how to achieve the opposite**: move focus back
to the webpage.

Since Brave browser and Google Chrome share multiple similaries even
on shortcuts (maybe due to the Brave Browser being built on top of the
open-source Chromium Web core), I tried shortcuts that people said
would do the trick on Chrome, see links
[1](https://superuser.com/questions/846647/keyboard-shortcut-to-get-focus-webpage-after-selecting-address-bar)
[2](https://superuser.com/questions/1548437/what-is-the-opposite-command-to-ctrl-l-in-a-browser).

Unfortunately, I tried <kbd>F6</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>, 3 times <kbd>F6</kbd> and none of
them worked out.

I also tried finding it on the official [documentation of
Brave](https://support.brave.com/hc/en-us/articles/360032272171-What-keyboard-shortcuts-can-I-use-in-Brave-).
I found <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> on the *Address bar* section. But could not find
the opposite command in this (or other) section.

I also have Google Chrome installed (for professional reasons). And
the shortcuts above mentioned also did not work for me.

Since I have seen a macOS user saying that he could not do it in a
comment. **Maybe this is related to apple devices**.

Any idea on how to achieve this shortcut on an Apple device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out that, I can do this by pressing <kbd>esc</kbd> in Chrome 106.0.5249.61, a great update! But didn't try in Brave.

---- Outdated Answer ----

I had the same requirement in Chrome, and finally I found a trick, it also works in Brave.

Open the search engines at `chrome://settings/searchEngines` in Chrome, or `brave://settings/searchEngines` in Brave. Click "Add" in "Site search" section to add a new item with the following fields:

- Search engine: `Focus on web page`
- Shortcut: `f` or what you like and not used in search engines
- URL with %s in place of query: `javascript:`

After saving, <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> to focus to the location bar (keeping the whole url is selected), then type `f`, maybe the `Focus on web page` is the first choice and selected by default in the drop list, you just press <kbd>return</kbd> to focus back to the page content (the origin url is still in the location bar).

If the `Focus on web page` is not the first choice and not selected by default, you need choose a better "Shortcut".

Comment: Awesome! This is one of the most elegant hacks I can remember! haha Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In Chromium based browsers there's a built in shortcut for this (though it's not the most intuitive). On Linux/Windows it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>, so I guess on OSX it will be either the same or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> (although I guess this could be an OSX bug).

Source: I work on Brave, and I've worked on Chrome in the past.